# sum of price-data according to the selection from multi select dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, drop-down-menu

as per the selection i want total of data-price to be displayed in totalamount input box

```
 <HTML>
   <body>
<form name="myForm" action="insert.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" id="myForm" style="width=90%" enctype="multipart/form-data" required>
<label>Test Name:</label>
     <select id="framework" name="framework[]" multiple class="form-control" >
<option value="HDL Cholesterol" data-price="180">HDL Cholesterol</option>
<option value="Total Cholesterol" data-price=180180180>Total Cholesterol</option>
<option value="Triglycerides (TG)" data-price=180285180>Triglycerides (TG)</option>
<option value="Sugar (Glucose) Fasting (FBS)" data-price=28570285>Sugar (Glucose) Fasting (FBS)</option>
<option value="Sugar (Glucose) Post Prandial (PPBS)" data-price=707070>Sugar (Glucose) Post Prandial (PPBS)</option>
<option value="Sugar (Glucose) Random (RBS)" data-price=707070>Sugar (Glucose) Random (RBS)</option>
<option value="Reticulocyte Count" data-price=7055070>Reticulocyte Count</option>
<option value="Total Thyroxine (T4)" data-price=550198550>Total Thyroxine (T4)</option>
<option value="Total Triiodothyronine (T3)" data-price=198198198>Total Triiodothyronine (T3)</option>
<option value="TSH (Thyroid Stimulating Hormone)" data-price=198240198>TSH (Thyroid Stimulating Hormone)</option>
<option value="Alkaline Phosphatase (ALP)" data-price=240210240>Alkaline Phosphatase (ALP)</option>
<option value="Aspartate Aminotransferase (SGOT )" data-price=210190210>Aspartate Aminotransferase (SGOT )</option>
<option value="Bilirubin Total" data-price=190130190>Bilirubin Total</option>
<option value="Calcium" data-price=130176130>Calcium</option>
<option value="Iron" data-price=176380176>Iron</option>
</select>
<td><label>Total Amount:</label><input type="number" name="totalamount">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution in 2 flavors. The reduce can be used for either method of course, but in the jQuery way, I tried to stick with jQuery methods.

**VanillaJS**

You can just tally it up with an `array.reduce()` function as it's being changed using a `change` event listener. Keep the variable global so you can reference it elsewhere (like in form.submit).

This line, explained:

```
totalVal = [...e.target.querySelectorAll('option:checked')] // get the HTML collection of selected option elements and convert that into an iterable array using the  [...] spread syntax
            .reduce((b, a) => // b is the accumulating value, a is the current iterating element
                (b + +a.dataset.price) // convert the price data-attribute to a number using the shorthand +
             , 0); // b starts out as zero and we add to it
```

```js
let totalVal = 0;
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  document.querySelector('#framework').addEventListener('change', e => {
    totalVal = [...e.target.querySelectorAll('option:checked')].reduce((b, a) => (b + +a.dataset.price), 0);
    document.querySelector('[name=totalamount]').value = totalVal
  })
})
```

```html
<form name="myForm" action="insert.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" id="myForm" style="width=90%" enctype="multipart/form-data" required>
  <label>Test Name:</label>
  <select id="framework" name="framework[]" multiple class="form-control">
    <option value="HDL Cholesterol" data-id="1" data-price="180">HDL Cholesterol</option>
    <option value="Total Cholesterol" data-id="2" data-price="180180180">Total Cholesterol</option>
    <option value="Triglycerides (TG)" data-id="3" data-price="180285180">Triglycerides (TG)</option>
    <option value="Sugar (Glucose) Fasting (FBS)" data-id="4" data-price="28570285">Sugar (Glucose) Fasting (FBS)</option>
    <option value="Sugar (Glucose) Post Prandial (PPBS)" data-id="5" data-price="707070">Sugar (Glucose) Post Prandial (PPBS)</option>
    <option value="Sugar (Glucose) Random (RBS)" data-id="6" data-price="707070">Sugar (Glucose) Random (RBS)</option>
    <option value="Reticulocyte Count" data-id="7" data-price="7055070">Reticulocyte Count</option>
    <option value="Total Thyroxine (T4)" data-id="8" data-price="550198550">Total Thyroxine (T4)</option>
    <option value="Total Triiodothyronine (T3)" data-id="9" data-price="198198198">Total Triiodothyronine (T3)</option>
    <option value="TSH (Thyroid Stimulating Hormone)" data-id="10" data-price="198240198">TSH (Thyroid Stimulating Hormone)</option>
    <option value="Alkaline Phosphatase (ALP)" data-id="11" data-price="240210240">Alkaline Phosphatase (ALP)</option>
    <option value="Aspartate Aminotransferase (SGOT )" data-id="12" data-price="210190210">Aspartate Aminotransferase (SGOT )</option>
    <option value="Bilirubin Total" data-id="13" data-price="190130190">Bilirubin Total</option>
    <option value="Calcium" data-id="14" data-price="130176130">Calcium</option>
    <option value="Iron" data-id="15" data-price="176380176">Iron</option>
  </select>
  <hr>
  <label>Total Amount:</label><input type="number" name="totalamount">
</form>
```

**The jQuery Way**

```js
let total = 0;
let code = [];
$('#framework').on('change', function() {
  total = 0;
  code = [];
  $(this).find('option:selected').each(function() {
    total += +$(this).data('price');
    code.push($(this).data('id'));
  })
  $('#totalamount').val(total);
  $('#testcode').val(code.join(", "));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="myForm" action="insert.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" id="myForm" style="width=90%" enctype="multipart/form-data" required>
  <label>Test Name:</label>
  <select id="framework" name="framework[]" multiple class="form-control">
    <option value="HDL Cholesterol" data-id="1" data-price="180">HDL Cholesterol</option>
    <option value="Total Cholesterol" data-id="2" data-price="180180180">Total Cholesterol</option>
    <option value="Triglycerides (TG)" data-id="3" data-price="180285180">Triglycerides (TG)</option>
    <option value="Sugar (Glucose) Fasting (FBS)" data-id="4" data-price="28570285">Sugar (Glucose) Fasting (FBS)</option>
    <option value="Sugar (Glucose) Post Prandial (PPBS)" data-id="5" data-price="707070">Sugar (Glucose) Post Prandial (PPBS)</option>
    <option value="Sugar (Glucose) Random (RBS)" data-id="6" data-price="707070">Sugar (Glucose) Random (RBS)</option>
    <option value="Reticulocyte Count" data-id="7" data-price="7055070">Reticulocyte Count</option>
    <option value="Total Thyroxine (T4)" data-id="8" data-price="550198550">Total Thyroxine (T4)</option>
    <option value="Total Triiodothyronine (T3)" data-id="9" data-price="198198198">Total Triiodothyronine (T3)</option>
    <option value="TSH (Thyroid Stimulating Hormone)" data-id="10" data-price="198240198">TSH (Thyroid Stimulating Hormone)</option>
    <option value="Alkaline Phosphatase (ALP)" data-id="11" data-price="240210240">Alkaline Phosphatase (ALP)</option>
    <option value="Aspartate Aminotransferase (SGOT )" data-id="12" data-price="210190210">Aspartate Aminotransferase (SGOT )</option>
    <option value="Bilirubin Total" data-id="13" data-price="190130190">Bilirubin Total</option>
    <option value="Calcium" data-id="14" data-price="130176130">Calcium</option>
    <option value="Iron" data-id="15" data-price="176380176">Iron</option>
  </select>
  <hr>
  <label>Test Code:</label><input type="text" id="testcode" name="testcode">

  <label>Total Amount:</label><input type="number" id="totalamount" name="totalamount">

</form>
```

Comment: can you please help me with below function

Comment: Yes, check my updated answer. They way you were adding the values together was problematic. It's better to add them all each time rather than incremenetally. If this helped solve your question, please accept as the answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

i am using below function can you please he

```
on deselecting dropdown option, value remains with no changes
function is to get comma separated testcode to testcode inputbox and totalamount to totalamoun text box 
        <html>`enter code here`
    <body>
          // query to fetch data from database
        $data="";
        $query = "SELECT testcode,testname,mrp FROM pricelist";
        $resultSet = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        if ($resultSet)
        {
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultSet)) {
            $data .="<option value='".$row['testname']."' data-price='".$row['mrp']."' data-id='".$row['testcode']."'>".$row['testname']."</option>";
          }
        }
        //form 
        <div class="form-group1">
        <label>Test Name:</label>
             <select id="framework" name="framework[]" multiple class="form-control" >
                  <?php echo $data; ?>
             </select>
            </div>
          </td>    
          <td><label>Test Code:</label><input type="text" id="testcode" name="testcode"></td>    
        <tr class="line_items">    
          <td><label>Total Amount:</label><input type="number" id="totalamount" name="totalamount">
        //jquery function
        <script>
        var total=0;
        var code="";
        $('#framework').on('change', function(){
          var mPrice = $(this).find('option:selected').data('price');
          var mCode = $(this).find('option:selected:last').data('id');
          if (mPrice != null){
            total+=mPrice;
            code +=mCode+',';
            $('#totalamount').val(total);
            $('#testcode').val(code);
          } else {
            
          }
        });
    </body>
        </html>
```